# How Can I Make Two (Or More) Usb Ports Act LIke One?

Tags: usb, port, usb-storage, usb-3, data-transfer

From what I understand, usb 3.0 storage devices have a higher data transfer rate (though it also depends on other factors), and that they're backwards-compatible with usb 2.0. However, when used in a 2.0 port, (assuming it's not limited by other factors), the data transfer speeds are lowered because only four pins are in use instead of nine. If I had an adapter that could use the pins on multiple ports and connect them to the 3.0 pins on the storage device, I should see a gain closer to the 3.0 transfer rate (I think). 
How could I make a something like this?

Comment: No, this would not work. USB 2.0 doesn't work that way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Can you be a little more specific on what parts of 2.0 wouldn't work?

Comment: This is not how USB works, it does not support bonding / link aggregation natively. Putting together two USB2 ports does not make a USB3 port.

Comment: "This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center." – ncdownpat, DavidPostill, BlueBerry - Vignesh4303

Comment: I Usb isn't computer hardware, then I don't know what is. I'm not trying to be a jerk, but there are a lot of question on here about Usb.

Comment: and it is not about …

    programming and software development,
    video games or consoles,
    websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
    electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, **except insofar as they interface with your computer,**
    issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
    asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation,

Comment: Direct quote from the rules: see above.

Answer (score 2):

You cannnot do this. It will not work.

The extra lines on a USB3 socket are not simply another USB2 port, they are an entirely new connection method for fast transfers that are somewhat akin to PCI-e lanes. The reason for backwards compatibility is because USB3 is actually two connections in one, a USB2 connection to establish capability and transfer control data (which can still be used for normal data) and a new set of pins for a superspeed connection.

Take away the superspeed connection and you still have a fully functional USB2 device, the same is not true of taking away the USB2 connection, you are not left with a fully usable device.

If you were to break out the extra wires of a USB3 socket and plug them into a USB2 socket then at best it would do nothing at all and at worst it could damage one or both devices.